# Customized scaffold templates

Tags: phoenix-framework

I've changed the following files to have a customized scaffold generator which saves a ton of work in the development process. The `deps` directory is in `.gitignore` so that's not a valid way to share those changes with other developers in the team. What is a good way to customize those default templates so that everybody in the development team can use them?

```
$ tree deps/phoenix/priv/templates/phoenix.gen.html
deps/phoenix/priv/templates/phoenix.gen.html
├── controller.ex
├── controller_test.exs
├── edit.html.eex
├── form.html.eex
├── index.html.eex
├── new.html.eex
├── show.html.eex
└── view.ex
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mix task look at first to the `priv` folder in your project if there nothing exists the default of phoenix dep will used.

Make a copy of `deps/phoenix/priv/templates/phoenix.gen.html` to `priv/templates/phoenix.gen.html` and it will work.

I'm not sure if there some documentation about this function, but you can look at `deps/phoenix/lib/mix/tasks/phoenix.gen.html.ex` you see at the bottom the function `paths`. That define the lookup to `./` and after them phoenix dep.

```
defp paths do
  [".", :phoenix]
end
```

Hope this helps.